# Why is the runtime of my python code so long, and what can I do to make it run faster?

Tags: python, performance, sympy, numeric, modeling

I just wrote some python code for my thesis. For some reason it is taking an upsurdly large amount of time to calculate the final value. Upon closer inspection it has something to do with the Sk array in the code, however to me it doesn't seem like that is a particularly costly calculation. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong in terms of coding the problem, and what can I do to obtain the same numerical result while cutting down my run-time? I attached the code below.

```
#Finding Optimal Values For Helix
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import  L


#Initalization of variables
omega_list = []
Rd = 1 #Inner Radius
td = 1 #Thickness Radius
h = 1 #height
l = 1 # Length
lamb = 2*sym.pi*h #Wavelength
mu = 1 #Don't touch Viscosity
q = 0.09*lamb #Don't touch
tau = sym.Matrix([[0],[0],[1]])
x = np.linspace(0.001, 10, num = 5 )

#For Loop For Optimization
for h in x:
    
#     print(i)
    #Distance to center of Mass
    r1 =  Rd*sym.cos(sym.abc.s)-(6*h**2*Rd)/(3*Rd**2+4*sym.pi**2*h**2)
    r2 = Rd*sym.sin(sym.abc.s)+(6*h**2*Rd)/(3*Rd**2+4*sym.pi**2*h**2)
    r3 = h*sym.abc.s-(3*sym.pi*h**2*Rd**2+6*sym.pi*h**2)/(3*Rd**2+4*sym.pi**2*h**2)
    print('again')
    #Frenet Frame Components
    t = np.array([[-Rd*sym.sin(sym.abc.s)],
                [Rd*sym.cos(sym.abc.s)],
                [h]])/sym.sqrt(Rd**2+h**2)
    n = np.array([[-Rd*sym.cos(sym.abc.s)],
                [-Rd*sym.sin(sym.abc.s)],
                [0]])
    b = np.array([[sym.sin(sym.abc.s)],
                [-sym.cos(sym.abc.s)],
                [Rd/h]])/sym.sqrt(Rd**2+h**2)*h
    
    #Skew Matrix
    Sk = np.array([[0, -r3, r2],
                [r3, 0, -r1],
                [-r2, r1, 0]])

    
    #Frenet Frame Assembly
    R = np.hstack((t,n,b))

    #Drag Matrix
    C = np.array([[l*(2*sym.pi*mu)/sym.log(2*q/td), 0, 0],
                [0,l*(4*sym.pi*mu)/sym.log(2*q/(td+0.5)) , 0],
                [0, 0, l*(4*sym.pi*mu)/sym.log(2*q/td)]])
    
    #Ressistance Matrix Assembly
    R11 = -1*R@C@R.transpose()
    R12 = R@C@R.transpose()@Sk
    R21 = -1*Sk@R@C@R.transpose()
    R22 = Sk@R@C@R.transpose()@Sk
    
    R11 = sym.Matrix([R11[0,:], R11[1,:], R11[2,:]])
    R12 = sym.Matrix([R12[0,:], R12[1,:], R12[2,:]])
    R21 = sym.Matrix([R21[0,:], R21[1,:], R21[2,:]])
    R22 = sym.Matrix([R22[0,:], R22[1,:], R22[2,:]])
    
    #Integration of Ressistance
    R11 = R11.integrate((sym.abc.s, 0, 2*sym.pi))
    R12 = R12.integrate((sym.abc.s, 0, 2*sym.pi))
    R21 = R21.integrate((sym.abc.s, 0, 2*sym.pi))
    R22 = R22.integrate((sym.abc.s, 0, 2*sym.pi))
    print('wtf^2')
    #Move Around to Isolate the Angular Velocity Omega
    ROmega = -1*R21@Sk+R22
    print('wtf')
    Omega = ROmega.inv()@tau
    print('good')
    Omega_final = (Omega[0,0]**2+Omega[1,0]**2+Omega[2,0]**2)
    print('all good')
    omega_list.append(Omega_final)
    print('ik')
    #Find the Velocity
    Sk@Omega

#Plot the Graphs
print("Omega:", omega_list)

print(x)
#plt.plot([x], [omega_final])
for i in omega_list:
    plt.plot(x, omega_list)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How long is an "absurdly long time"?

Comment: I let it run for 10-15 minutes and it wasn't done with the first loop, as the print() functions I implemented did not print a second time.

Comment: Nice print statements lol. Some advice: symbolic computation is just slow. It seems you're doing a matrix inverse in there which is costing a bit of time, and while I didn't look at the rest, I think it's not unexpectedly slow, but of course I don't know the full details. Also, I suggest to actually time code fragments to identify bad lines. You can import the time module and then use time.perf_counter() to get the current time.

Comment: @JerryHalisberry, would you mind showing me a snippet example of how to do this since I have never done so before and I am relatively new to python. As well is there any numerical trick python can do to get around the symbolic computation and yield the same result?

Comment: @DeCarabas Sure, here you go: https://pastebin.com/w50s2GmS. If you want to know how to optimize some kind of computation, I suggest you edit the question to make it a little more clear what is happening in the code, and also try to ask on math.stackexchange (those guys probably know some nice tricks).

Comment: While you use `numpy` arrays, the contain `symbols` and thus are object dtype.  So you don't get any numpy speedup. I don't know how essential the `sympy` stuff is, or whether it can be rewritten as a numeric `numpy` and `scipy` calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is intentional, but your code essentially calculates a few matrix multiplications as a function of s. R21 and R22 are not functions of s though. And omega is a multiplication of functions of s together with R21 and R22. I assume you are trying to plot omega as a function of s.

As @hpaulj stated, it might not be necessary to use SymPy if you are not interested in your velocity calculation. Here is a purely numeric version. My answer is atrocious but it's fast. I'm sure someone can easily come along and make it more readable.

```py
# Finding Optimal Values For Helix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Initalization of variables
omega_list = []
Rd = 1  # Inner Radius
td = 1  # Thickness Radius
h = 1  # height
l = 1  # Length
lamb = 2 * np.pi * h  # Wavelength
mu = 1  # Don't touch Viscosity
q = 0.09 * lamb  # Don't touch
tau = np.array([[0], [0], [1]])

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=5)
x[0] += 1/1000

# For Loop For Optimization
print(x)
for h in x:
    print(f"Beginning loop where h={h}")

    # Distance to center of Mass
    r1 = lambda s: Rd * np.cos(s) - (6 * h ** 2 * Rd) / (3 * Rd ** 2 + 4 * np.pi ** 2 * h ** 2)
    r2 = lambda s: Rd * np.sin(s) + (6 * h ** 2 * Rd) / (3 * Rd ** 2 + 4 * np.pi ** 2 * h ** 2)
    r3 = lambda s: h * s - (3 * np.pi * h ** 2 * Rd ** 2 + 6 * np.pi * h ** 2) / (
            3 * Rd ** 2 + 4 * np.pi ** 2 * h ** 2)

    # Frenet Frame Components
    t = lambda s: np.array([[-Rd * np.sin(s)],
                  [Rd * np.cos(s)],
                  [h]]) / np.sqrt(Rd ** 2 + h ** 2)
    n = lambda s: np.array([[-Rd * np.cos(s)],
                  [-Rd * np.sin(s)],
                  [0]])
    b = lambda s: np.array([[np.sin(s)],
                  [-np.cos(s)],
                  [Rd / h]]) / np.sqrt(Rd ** 2 + h ** 2) * h

    # Skew Matrix
    Sk = lambda s: np.array([[0, -r3(s), r2(s)],
                   [r3(s), 0, -r1(s)],
                   [-r2(s), r1(s), 0]])

    # Frenet Frame Assembly
    R = lambda s: np.hstack((t(s), n(s), b(s)))

    # Drag Matrix
    C = lambda s: np.array([[l * (2 * np.pi * mu) / np.log(2 * q / td), 0, 0],
                  [0, l * (4 * np.pi * mu) / np.log(2 * q / (td + 1/2)), 0],
                  [0, 0, l * (4 * np.pi * mu) / np.log(2 * q / td)]])

    # Ressistance Matrix Assembly
    R21 = lambda s: -1 * Sk(s) @ R(s) @ C(s) @ R(s).transpose()
    R22 = lambda s: Sk(s) @ R(s) @ C(s) @ R(s).transpose() @ Sk(s)

    # Integration of Resistance
    R21 = np.array([[quad(lambda s: R21(s)[i, j], 0, 2*np.pi)[0] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])
    R22 = np.array([[quad(lambda s: R22(s)[i, j], 0, 2*np.pi)[0] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])
    print("Finished integration")

    # Move Around to Isolate the Angular Velocity Omega
    ROmega = lambda s: -1 * R21 @ Sk(s) + R22
    Omega = lambda s: np.linalg.inv(ROmega(s).astype(float)) @ tau
    Omega_final = lambda s: (Omega(s)[0, 0] ** 2 + Omega(s)[1, 0] ** 2 + Omega(s)[2, 0] ** 2)

    # Cannot find the Velocity as a function of s

    # Adding lambda functions to the array does not work
    lam = Omega_final
    x_vals = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    omega_list.append(np.vectorize(lam)(x_vals))

# Plot the Graphs
for (i, omega) in enumerate(omega_list[0:1]):
    lam = omega
    x_vals = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    plt.plot(x_vals, omega, label=f"h={x[i]}")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This runs in ~1 second.

If you want a symbolic version it is possible but it is longer. These expressions are very large but we can speed things up slightly: integration after matrix multiplication can be made faster if we expand the linear combinations. This is why `expand(...).evalf()` is used so many times. `simplify()` takes too long.

```py
# Finding Optimal Values For Helix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

# Initalization of variables
omega_list = []
Rd = 1  # Inner Radius
td = 1  # Thickness Radius
h = 1  # height
l = 1  # Length
lamb = 2 * sym.pi * h  # Wavelength
mu = 1  # Don't touch Viscosity
q = sym.Rational("0.09") * lamb  # Don't touch
tau = sym.Matrix([[0], [0], [1]])

x = list(range(0, 10, 2))
x[0] += sym.S(1)/1000

s = sym.symbols("s", real=True)

# For Loop For Optimization
# h took to long to invert the matrix if it was a symbol
for h in x:
    print(f"Beginning loop where h={h}")

    # Distance to center of Mass
    r1 = Rd * sym.cos(s) - (6 * h ** 2 * Rd) / (3 * Rd ** 2 + 4 * sym.pi ** 2 * h ** 2)
    r2 = Rd * sym.sin(s) + (6 * h ** 2 * Rd) / (3 * Rd ** 2 + 4 * sym.pi ** 2 * h ** 2)
    r3 = h * s - (3 * sym.pi * h ** 2 * Rd ** 2 + 6 * sym.pi * h ** 2) / (
            3 * Rd ** 2 + 4 * sym.pi ** 2 * h ** 2)

    # Frenet Frame Components
    t = sym.Matrix([[-Rd * sym.sin(s)],
                  [Rd * sym.cos(s)],
                  [h]]) / sym.sqrt(Rd ** 2 + h ** 2)
    n = sym.Matrix([[-Rd * sym.cos(s)],
                  [-Rd * sym.sin(s)],
                  [0]])
    b = sym.Matrix([[sym.sin(s)],
                  [-sym.cos(s)],
                  [Rd / h]]) / sym.sqrt(Rd ** 2 + h ** 2) * h

    # Skew Matrix
    Sk = sym.Matrix([[0, -r3, r2],
                   [r3, 0, -r1],
                   [-r2, r1, 0]])
    Sk = sym.simplify(Sk)

    # Frenet Frame Assembly
    # R = np.hstack((t, n, b))
    R = t.row_join(n).row_join(b)
    R = sym.simplify(R)

    # Drag Matrix
    C = sym.Matrix([[l * (2 * sym.pi * mu) / sym.log(2 * q / td), 0, 0],
                  [0, l * (4 * sym.pi * mu) / sym.log(2 * q / (td + sym.S(1)/2)), 0],
                  [0, 0, l * (4 * sym.pi * mu) / sym.log(2 * q / td)]])
    C = sym.simplify(C)

    # Ressistance Matrix Assembly
    R21 = -1 * sym.expand(sym.expand(Sk @ R) @ C) @ R.transpose()
    R21 = sym.expand(R21).evalf()
    R22 = sym.expand(sym.expand(sym.expand(Sk @ R) @ C) @ R.transpose()) @ Sk
    R22 = sym.expand(R22).evalf()

    # Integration of Resistance
    R21 = sym.integrate(R21, (s, 0, 2 * sym.pi))
    R22 = sym.integrate(R22, (s, 0, 2 * sym.pi))
    print("Finished integration")

    # Move Around to Isolate the Angular Velocity Omega
    ROmega = -1 * sym.expand(R21 @ Sk) + R22
    ROmega = sym.expand(ROmega).evalf()
    print(f"ROmega = {ROmega}")
    Omega = ROmega.inv() @ tau
    print(f"Omega = {Omega}")
    Omega_final = (Omega[0, 0] ** 2 + Omega[1, 0] ** 2 + Omega[2, 0] ** 2).evalf()
    print(f"Omega_final = {Omega_final}")
    omega_list.append(Omega_final)
    print('ik')

    # Find the Velocity
    print(f"Sk @ Omega = {sym.expand(Sk @ Omega)}")

# Omega list is massive
print(f"omega_list = {omega_list}")

# Plot the Graphs
for (i, omega) in enumerate(omega_list):
    lam = sym.lambdify((s,), omega)
    s_vals = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    plt.plot(s_vals, lam(s_vals), label=f"h={x[i]}")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This produces the same plot but takes maybe a minute on my machine.